# htaccess multiple rewrite urls to same folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm new with using htaccess and I was wondering I have 3 urls I want to rewrite to the same folder

```
   /articles-pages.php?page_name=$1
   /articles-posts.php?page_name=$1     
   /articles-interviews.php?page_name=$1
```

and would like them all to rewrite to articles/$1

Is it possible or would I have to put them under separate folders. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

update: my htaccess file looks like this

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://www.about-muscle.com/404.php
 ErrorDocument 500 http://www.about-muscle.com/500.php

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page_name=([^&]+)(?:&|$) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^articles-(interviews|pages|posts)\.php$ /articles/%1? [R=301,L,NE]


 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|bodybuilding\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|bodybuilders\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|personal\-training\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|fitness\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|supplements\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|nutrition\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|female\-fitness\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|weight\-loss\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|magazine\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|equipment\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|health\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|other\-links\.html) - [L]
 RewriteRule ^(index\.php|links\.html) - [L]

 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^about-muscle.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.about-muscle.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php

 Options +FollowSymLinks

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/name/(.*)/ exercises/detail.php?name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/name/(.*) exercises/detail.php?name=$1   

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/muscle/(.*)/ exercises/muscle.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/muscle/(.*) exercises/muscle.php?page_name=$1    

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/type/(.*)/ exercises/type.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/type/(.*) exercises/type.php?page_name=$1

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/equipment/(.*)/ exercises/equipment.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/equipment/(.*) exercises/equipment.php?page_name=$1

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/mechanics/(.*)/ exercises/mechanics.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/mechanics/(.*) exercises/mechanics.php?page_name=$1

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule exercises/force/(.*)/ exercises/force.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule exercises/force/(.*) exercises/force.php?page_name=$1

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule writers/(.*).php writers/$1/

 RewriteRule writers/(.*)/ writer-pages.php?page_name=$1
 RewriteRule writers/(.*) writer-pages.php?page_name=$1

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule go/(.*)/ goto.php?m=$1
 RewriteRule go/(.*) goto.php?m=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+articles-(?:interviews|pages|posts)\.php\?page_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /articles/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/.]+)/?$ /article-pages.php?page_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @anubhava but that isn't working. Any idea's why or what else I could maybe try.

Comment: Provide as much details as you can. `isn't working` doesn't tell me anything about the problem. What URL didn't work? What error you got? Where is your .htaccess located? What are other rule in there (if any) etc etc.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, none of the pages are rewriting. they are just returning a 404 page not found.

Comment: That answers only half of my question. Repeating:  Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess? Q4. Did you make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled?

Comment: Hi @anubhava, sorry im new with htaccess. I only have the one htaccess file which is located in the website root, mod_rewrite should be enabled because my other url rewrites are working fine. I have updated my code above with everything that's on my htaccess file. Im new with htaccess so it may not be the best written.

Comment: Hi @anubhava , code still does the same thing it doesn't rewrite to the url, as if the code is being ignored

Comment: Hi @anubhava sorry I just noticed it works for article-pages.php but not for the articles-interviews.php and articles-posts.php

Comment: The only way it can work for all 3 if you allow pretty URL to be: `/articles/interviews/$1/` and `/articles/pages/$1/` and `/articles/posts/$1/`

Comment: Let me know if this is ok with you then I can edit rule accordingly

Comment: Thanks for you help @anubhava , ideally I didn't want to have to do that becase it would mean lot of restructure to my site. Would it maybe be possible to do it with just 2 of the pages rather than 3.

Comment: See once a page has been redirected to pretty URL it needs to have all the info to be rewritten back to actual internal URL.

Comment: Redirected pretty URI is: `/articles/abc123` which doesn't give any info whether it should be redirected to `/articles-pages.php` OR `/articles-posts.php` OR `/articles-interviews.php` As an alternative can you have pretty URL as `/articles-interviews/$1/` OR `/articles-pages/$1/` etc?

Comment: I see, so if I change to this url would I have to redirect all my old pages individually to the new urls.

Comment: No you don't need to change all old URLs, that can be done via .htaccess Whenever you make changes in future then you can slows adapt to new URL scheme till then .htaccess will take care of that.